# Do Catholics believe that people can be saved without hearing the name of Christ?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, reformed-theology, gospels, catholic-catechism

Do Catholics believe that people can be saved without hearing the name of Christ?

I came across this while listening to [John MacArthur on Catholicism, and Billy Graham](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyQecMfHUq4)

What do Catholics believe is essential to salvation?